# Run a task schedule within asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net application which needs to call an API very 5 minutes to get the latest data from a server. Currently, we plan to 1) build a console application and then use windows server task scheduler to schedule it; or, 2) build a windows service for this.

Is it possible to do this within asp.net application? If yes, how?

We just want to see whether there are better solution out there.

thanks

Comment: You *could* do this from your asp.net application with a `System.Threading.Timer` (or an async loop with `Task.Delay`), as long as you code for failure with the assumption that your application might be killed at any point by the hosting environment. If your periodic task is particularly intensive, this might have a toxic effect on the web-server's ability to handle requests in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 3):

As of .NET 4.5.2 there is a `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` API that allows you to create your own reoccuring task implementation ([see here for details and examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/)) however I would recommend taking a look at some popular and more established open source libraries available. The most popular being [hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/)

After installing it via Nuget (`PM> Install-Package Hangfire`) and configuring it with your ASP.NET MVC application like so:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");

    app.UseHangfireDashboard(); //optional
    app.UseHangfireServer(); 
}
```

You can start to create fire and forget schedules, delayed or reoccurring schedules like so:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget"));
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed"), TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Daily Job"), Cron.Daily);
```

What's also really nice about Hangfire is that it's got a really polished reporting feature that allows you to monitor your sheduled tasks:

[image]

You can see more screenshots of the [reporting dashboard here](http://hangfire.io/overview.html#integrated-monitoring-ui).

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net is really for providing an HTML user interface to users. As the solution you are wanting does not need a user interface, creating it as an ASP.Net application makes the job of installing and maintaining the application that much harder.

[Here is a post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) talking about the dangers of recurring background tasks in ASP.NET, it includes examples of how to do it.
Probably best to use a library such as [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to avoid doing it yourself.

As another option, you can even create a powershell script that is kicked off by the task scheduler.